# How to link static files for django cms?(first lounch)

Tags: django-cms

Did everythink from [this](https://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/install.html).

But when I open my site I get `"If you don't see the django CMS logo at the top, make sure you linked the static/cms folder to your static files."` and site looks weird.

Comment: What are your static file settings?

Comment: Are u using the `./manage.py runserver` test server? If not, make sure to run `./manage.py collectstatic`.